# problems with unsigned char

Tags: char, unsigned

I have using Aaron Liddiment's excellent Ledtext library.
It includes code

```
unsigned char TxtDemo[] = { EFFECT_HSV "\x10\xff\xff" "TEST" };
ScrollingMsg.SetText((unsigned char *)TxtDemo, sizeof(TxtDemo) - 1);
```

I have a socket connection which outputs a string. I want to dynamically replace the word "TEST" with this string. I have tried:

```
unsigned char TxtDemo[] = { EFFECT_HSV "\x00\xff\xff" };
String txt="my text";
strcat( TxtDemo, txt.c_str() );
```

no good... help please

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you explain why "no good"? That is, what the actual problem is and what you expect?

Comment: This particular effort produces error....invalid conversion from 'unsigned char*' to 'char*'. I've tried various combinations of strcat, sprintf and strcpy but I get either a compile error or no output to display.

Comment: I can't test this (no arduino etc) so I can only suggest you do `String Color = (EFFECT_HSV "\x00\xff\xff"); String txt = "my text"; String TxtDemo = Color + txt; ScrollingMsg.SetText((unsigned char *)TxtDemo.data(), TxtDemo.length());`

Comment: Note you can't use `strcat` and similar C functions because they expect '\0' terminated C strings, and your original TxtDemo may contain '\0' chars, which will make strcat believe the string is shorter than you intend. Also, `strcat()` writes into the destination so you need to make sure there's enough space allocated for the result.

Comment: thank you petre This produces 'class String' has no member named 'data' so  I've changed so my code to String Color = (EFFECT_HSV "\x00\xff\xff"); String txt = "my text"; String TxtDemo = Color + txt; ScrollingMsg.SetText((unsigned char *)TxtDemo.c_str(), TxtDemo.length()); this compiles but produces no output on display.

Comment: Oh it's not `std::string`? Well anyway, use `c_str()`, sure. As I said, I'm sorry I can't help you with the led library. You could try `cout`ing the `TxtDemo` to see what it contains. Or try replacing Color with a short normal string and see what happens.

Comment: And consider adding tags for C/C++ and arduino for you question, it should attract people with knowlege in those areas.

Comment: petre thanks for your help. I've given up on this library and gone back to basic "fastled" library.